# LDAP attribute for image/png

Tags: ldap, schema

Like the jpegPhoto-attribute (`0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.60`) of inetOrgPerson for the mime-type `image/jpeg` - I'm searching a LDAP-attribute for `image/png`.

Does such a `pngPhoto` or `pngImage` exists?

Comment: PNG's weren't nearly as well know as JPEG's when LDAP was actively evolving.  http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/History%20of%20LDAP